# Perl script that recurses through a directory tree

Tags: perl, recursion, directory

I want to write a Perl script that starts at the top of a directory tree (provided in the command line arguments) and recursively moves through each sub-directory, performing a certain action on each file.

I'm using `finddepth` for this, however it does not seem to work when I run the script on a directory that is two levels or more from the base directory.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use File::Copy;
use File::Find;
use File::Basename;
use File::Path;

finddepth(\&file_list, @ARGV);

sub file_list {

    my ($file_path, $name, $path, $suffix);

    $file_path = $File::Find::name;

    ($name, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($file_path, /\.*/);

    my $fullname = $name . $suffix;
    my $file = $fullname;

    if ($file =~ /^[^\.].*[^\.pl]$/) {

        copy($file, "$file.orig");

        open(FILE, "$file");
        my @file_data = <FILE>;
        close(FILE);

        open(FOUT, ">$file") or die " \n File cannot be opened !";

        foreach my $line (@file_data) {
            if ($line =~ /^\s+Error:/) {
                $line =~ s/([^-]\d+)/ \*\*/gc;
                print FOUT $line;
            }
            else {
                print FOUT $line;
            }
        }
        close(FOUT);
    }
}
```

The following warnings/errors are consistently thrown:

1. Read on closed filehandle
2. File cannot be opened !

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I've tried to make my question as specific as possible. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thank you.

Comment: You are using `strict`, but why not `warnings`?

Comment: Where do those warnings/errors get thrown?  Don't they show a filename?  A line number?

Comment: What is your regular expression `/^[^\.].*[^\.pl]$/` supposed to match?

Comment: This is the warning that gets thrown Read on closed filehandle <FILE> and File cannot be opened is thrown at Line 37. Also, I removed warnings from the code just to see what would happen. It should ideally be there.

@Borodin I don't want my regex to match files that either start with a '.' or end with a '.pl'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open the file because `$file` happens to be a directory at that point in time, so you'll need to add a check for that.

It's probably worth adding an `or die` statement when opening the file for reading.

Also note that `File::Find` sets `$_` to the current file name, so the 5 lines you take to produce `$file` are actually unnecessary.

Comment: Well thats what I thought too. But then I went to the perldocs page for File::Find (http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) and what I understand from there is that find() automatically does a chdir() for each directory found and then resumes it's search for files from there. Since finddepth is basically the same as find, it should ideally work.

Comment: The point about `chdir()` is right. That's the reason why you can just call open on the filename and don't need the full path.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't perl take care of this issue ? And I'm calling open on the filename ie $fullname = $name.$suffix, not the file path.

Comment: To clarify, the main issue is that `$file` can be either a file name or a directory name as you traverse the tree. But you're not recognising when it is a directory name. Use the `-f` or `-d` file tests to check this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.

- `use warnings` is preferable to the command-line `-w`
- Declare your variables at their first point of use, not in a block at the top of the the subroutine
- Use the three-parameter form of `open`, and lexical file handles
- When checking the status of an `open` call, put the built-in variable `$!` in the `die` string so that you know *why* the open failed
- Don't put scalar variables inside double quotes. It is probably unnecessary and under some circumstances can break your code. It is highly unlikely to do anything you want

This rewrite of your program uses `use autodie` to avoid the need for explicit `open ... or die $!` statements. It uses `rename` to change the name of the file instead of copying it and overwriting the original.

Instead of reading the entire file into memory, I open the renamed file and read it line by line, editing and writing each line to the new file

I have written it so that it ignores files that begin with a dot or end with `.pl` - I hope that's right. I am also very dubious about your substitution `s/[^-]\d+/ **/g` which looks for a sequence of digits preceded by a character that isn't a hyphen; is that right?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;
no autodie 'unlink';

use File::Find 'finddepth';

finddepth(\&file_list, @ARGV);

sub file_list {

  return unless -f;
  return if /^\./ or /\.pl$/;

  my $file = $_;
  my $orig = "$file.orig";

  unlink $orig;
  rename $file, $orig;

  open my $infh, '<', $orig;
  open my $outfh, '>', $file;

  while (my $line = <$infh>) {
    if ($line =~ /^\s+Error:/) {
      $line =~ s/[^-]\d+/ **/g
    }
    print $outfh $line;
  }

  close $outfh;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the -f file test. My code is working fine after adding the -f test. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. I hope you have taken notice of my other points as they are practices that will help you write good, reliable code.

Comment: Yes , I have. As for my substitution, I'm trying to avoid substituting negative numbers. Why do you think it's dubious ? I'm just getting started at perl so I'm still struggling with regexes a bit.

Comment: Ah OK. You want "digits not preceded by a hyphen", which is different from "digits preceded by not-a-hypen". The problem with that regex is twofold. Firstly it won't match a number at the start of the string because it isn't preceded by anything, and secondly it includes the preceding character in the substitution so it will be deleted and replaced by a space, whatever it was originally. What you want is a negative look-behind - `s/(?<!-)\d+/**/`.

Comment: There is one problem with your regex. It's only replacing single digits preceded by a '-'. For example, -4 is being ignored but -54 becomes -5** after running the script. So I modified the regex you suggested to s/((?<!-) | (?<!-\d) | (?<!-\d{2}))\d+/\*\*/gc . This should ideally only work for up to 3 digits preceding the' -'. So -334 should be ignored but -3344 should become -334**. However it is now ignoring any number of digits that start with a '-'. Why do you think this is happening ?

Comment: The regex you are talking about is `$line =~ s/[^-]\d+/ **/g` which replaces any number of digits. Please post a new question with the code you are using and sample data that shows the problem.